# Adding a Key/Value to a Dictionary in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning Redux and having trouble trying to figure out how to add a key pair to a dictionary:

```
//Page Dictionary    
{
  randomId1: { aPageObj },
  randomId2: { aPageObj }, etc
}
```

I tried this but that doesn't work

```
//action
export function addPage( pageId, pageObj ) {
  return { type: types.ADD_PAGE, pageId, pageObj };
}

//reducer
case types.ADD_PAGE: {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    pages: {
      ...state.pages, action.pageId: action.pageObj
    }
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Still trying to figure out how to not mutate the state..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) of object literal (with `[]`):

```
pages: {
  ...state.pages, [action.pageId]: action.pageObj
}
```

Furthermore if you can use object spreas syntax, you can omit `Object.assign`, for example:

```
return {
  ...state,
  pages: {
    ...state.pages, [action.pageId]: action.pageObj
  }
}
```

Comment: argh that's it?  sigh ty.

Comment: ah i like that edit.. i've been using Object.assign for everything... ty for that

Comment: In your second example, you don't need the square brackets ?

Comment: Oh ok. I got excited. I thought that was possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Although we can store a map in redux, its not recommended - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1499.